# Do Big 3D Games Have Multiple Game Loops?

Tags: loops, 3d

Do they have one loop updating everything? Do they have multiple loops that update certain parts of the game?

Answer (score 1):

Many engines use many different techniques.

Some will run 1 main loop, some run use a thread pool, some run a simulation loop, and a out of sync render loop.

Want a more specific answer? ask a more specific question.